# What is the purpose of packages "provide" and "ifneeded" command in TCL?

Tags: package, tcl

I Want to know , What is the purpose of **packages** "provide" and "if-needed" commands in TCL ? Please any body clarify my doubts.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you read the wiki about [package provide](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1569) and [package ifneeded](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10006) before asking your question?

Comment: yeah, but i am not getting those points... Could someone explain better than wiki

Comment: i got these two points which is related to provide and ifneeded, could you please explain these two steps , what exactly provide is working? it will just return verion number if it is alread loaded ?..............                                                                     If it is already loaded (an earlier call to package provide) it will just return the version number.
If it is not yet loaded but it knows how to load it (by a previous call to package ifneeded) it will execute that script, does some checks (the package should be loaded, versions must match...) and return the version.

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: This is the flow i have understood, please let me know am i correct?............package re ----> package provide-----loaded ----version number
                      |
                      |------not loaded ---packa ifneed----tclpkgunknown-----it will check in auto_path----known means----tclpkgsetup-----then source requre package.
                                                 |
                                                 |--------known means------------tclpkgsetup-----then source requre package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`package provide`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/package.htm#M9) command goes in the definition code of a package to declare that a particular package with a particular version has been defined.

Here's a trivial example:

```
namespace eval ::foo {
    proc bar {} {
        puts "this is the bar procedure in the foo namespace"
    }
}
package provide foobar 1.1
```

The aim is that a package is a higher-level concept than just “oh, here's a bunch of files that you `source`”, even though that's quite possibly how it is implemented.

Some people prefer to put the `package provide` at the top of the script.

---

The [`package ifneeded`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/package.htm#M6) command is used to supply *metadata* about a package to Tcl *before* loading the package itself. It goes inside a script named `pkgIndex.tcl` (usually) in the same directory as your package implementation, and it is used to say “if you want to use the package with *this* name and *this* version, run *this* script”. The final bit you need to know about this is that the package discovery code (run when you ask for a package it doesn't know about) runs the `pkgIndex.tcl` scripts that it finds in contexts that define the variable `dir` to be the directory containing the `pkgIndex.tcl` script that is being run; you don't need to do anything special to relocate the package if you use that convention (which is really convenient).

An example that might match up with the above code:

```
package ifneeded foobar 1.1 [list source [file join $dir foobar.tcl]]
```

There is a library command to generate the `pkgIndex.tcl` scripts for you — [`pkg_mkIndex`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/pkgMkIndex.htm) — but I don't use it as it's not exactly difficult to write it by hand. (Note also that just because we've implemented the package with just a single Tcl script this time doesn't mean that it has to be done that way. It could also be many scripts, or shared libraries, or a mix of scripts and shared libraries. The user of the package shouldn't have to care about this.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply donal fellows,  i have understood like .... Provide is used to tell TCL interpreter that "This is the package and this is the version" have been loaded.....  And ifneed is used to filter files based on version in directory that mentioned in the packages to load in the TCL interpreter. please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need an example to see how these commands are working.

Building reusable libraries is a good topic in the tcl tutorial which explaines how package ifneeded, provide and require fit in.

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl31.html